# Bash variable returns "command not found" in OSX Terminal

Tags: macos, bash

I tried using some variables to rename a few files, but it failed miserably. I've tried different ways of getting it to work, but to no avail. As far as I understand the documentation, this is the correct way of doing things - however now I'm stumped...

Here's the code (as written in the file `rename_prefix.sh`):

```
 #!/bin/sh
 NEWPREF="LALA"
 OLDPREF="LULU"
 for f in $OLDPREF*; do mv $f $(echo $f | sed 's/^$OLDPREF/$NEWPREF/g'); done
```

Here's the error message:

```
 usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
   mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

Initially I thought the problem lay in using variables with what I assume are the regular expressions, but as can be seen from the error messages, the problem lies where the variables are first declared.

What's going on here?

Comment: variables are not interpreted in single quotes `'`. Try using double quotes `"` in the `sed` command e.g. `sed "s/^$OLDPREF/$NEWPREF/g"` or something similar

Comment: Are you certain there's no spaces, e.g. `NEWPREF ="LALA"` in your script ?

Comment: Oh man... bad. Almost definitely should be quoting `"$OLDPREF"` in the glob, and definitely definitely shouldn't be recycling it for use as a regex. Use parameter expansion for string manipulation of shell variables if at all possible. Lots of quoting issues here.

Comment: No spaces double-check: Affirmative! I am certain. Single quoting double quotes, and double quoting single quotes didn't work. Double quoting variable in the glob didn't work. Error message unchanged, suggesting the problem is the variable declaration and not the glob/regex line.

Comment: You can't have any quotes around globbing characters if you want filename expansion, single or double.  You almost certainly have some whitespace between variable name and the `=` to get those error messages.  Try: `od -xc rename_prefix.sh` to see "hidden" characters, like \r.

Comment: I do not: `NEWPREF='PPU'` There are no hidden spaces either. I'd see them with my eyes, and my program (Sublime Text 2) would report them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done entirely in the shell, which also avoids the possible problem of escaping metacharacters for the sed substitution patterns. It is also blazingly fast because it saves two forks per file renamed.

```
NEWPREF="LALA"
OLDPREF="LULU"
for f in "$OLDPREF"*; do
   mv "$f" "$NEWPREF${f#$OLDPREF}"
done
```

If you want to learn more about removing suffixes and prefixes from shell variable values, read up the [POSIX spec on parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) (which all of zsh, ksh, mksh, and bash support).

PS: The **only** way you can get an error like `rename_prefix.sh: line 2: NEWPREF: command not found` is if you had whitespace after `NEWPREF` and before the `=`. It looks very much like your program as posted is not exactly the program you ran. Did you type it instead of cut'n'paste it?

Comment: Error: `mv: rename ABY to PPU: No such file or directory`

Comment: What does `echo $OLDPREF*` expand to?

Comment: Whether you should use something like this answer or mine essentially depends upon whether `OLDPREF` is intended to be a pattern. If no, this has quoting issues. If yes, you should set `IFS=` in order to deal with whitespace characters, however it's generally not a good idea to put patterns into variables.

Comment: The poster explicitly gave the old and new prefixes as strings without metacharacters. Of course it is always good to state assumptions.

Comment: as you mentioned, it's pretty much the only way this can fail unless there were no glob matches. edit +1 anyway, it's a right answer for some definition of right. :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "expand to". In the error `OLDPREF="ABY"` instead of `OLDPREF="LULU"`. In any case it does not matter, as I've now got the code to work. Thank you! :)

Comment: *Expansion* is the process the shell performs when replacing globs or variables with their values. So simply enter `echo *` to see what `*` expands to. The error you got was because there was no file starting with ABY. For the script to work, there should be at least one matching file.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so assuming you don't require POSIX, and guessing about certain other details, here's the same thing with general corrections applied.

```
#!/bin/bash
newpref=LALA
oldpref=LULU

shopt -s nullglob

for f in "$oldperf"*; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f/#"$oldpref"/$newpref}"
done
```

or POSIX

```
#!/bin/sh
newpref=LALA
oldpref=LULU

for f in "$oldpref"*; do
    [ -e "$f" ] || break
    mv -- "$f" "${newpref}${f#"$oldpref"}"
done
```

Comment: What about keeping the case of variables consistent? oldpref != OLDPREF. And it is pref, not perf. This script certainly wasn't tested.

Comment: @Jens You should conventionally avoid all-caps variable names for purely internal purposes, as they may cause conflicts and can be mistaken for environment variables.

Comment: You misunderstand: you are using BOTH. One of them uninitialized. This can't work at all. And you also use both the proper spelling and misspelling (perf). Why didn't you bother to test run your script, which would immediately have shown all those errors?

Comment: @Jens I don't see this, I missed a few previously and edited.

Comment: @Jens Ah you mean s/pref/perf. I see. Thanks.

Comment: No, I meant s/perf/pref/, because it is meant to read "prefix", not "performance".

Comment: @Jens D'oh, Thanks for patience!

Comment: `OLDPREF` is simply short for "Old Prefix", hence the name. It is _not_ short for "Old Perforation"... I thought that was pretty clear from the code, but no matter xD as long as the code actually works.